# Gradle for this Spring Boot project + jsp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, gradle

Im using Gradle for this Spring boot project and my task is to create another jsp file , for example : index.jsp and do something that Spring boot can generate that index.jsp

My problem is when i create index.jsp in webapp -> WEB_INF -> index.jsp
it only return the message 'index' instead of what is in file index.

Application.java

```
package edu.msudenver.tsp.website;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

PledgeController.java

```
package edu.msudenver.tsp.website.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class PledgeController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHelloMessage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

}
```

index.jsp

```
> <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
> <html> <head>
>     <title>Hello Spring mvc</title> </head> <body>
```

Answer (score 3):

add dependencies for JSP

```
compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
```

and index.jsp PATH is **webapp/WEB_INF/jsp/index.jsp**.

if you want example, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp.

Comment: I create another directory named jsp under webapp/WEB_INF/jsp/index.jsp
And also add dependencies , but it still does not work :(

Comment: your prefix is actually WEB-INF, and the path is WEB_INF. They need to be the same

Comment: working for me. @ionut you have `@RestController` annotation. Use `@Controller`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@Controller` annotation instead of `@RestController` in your class `PledgeController`.

```
 @Controller
 public class PledgeController {


        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String getHelloMessage() {
            return "index";
        }
 }
```

Comment: I tried that then it got this error
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Mar 06 21:05:32 MST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's not about the java code. The only solution I found was switching to `maven`. The only change was `build.gradle` -> `pom.xml`, and nothing else in  the controller or jsp file, what you have there is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).